# Get a users instagram images without access tokens api

Tags: c#, jquery, instagram

I want to display a user's images on a website.

I don't wont the users visiting the site to have to login and authenticate themselves, and from what I've read about the access tokens they seem to expire after a while.

So, how can I display my images on a web page without beeing worried about the access token expiring?

Is there any way of using a username and password in my code behind?

Answer (score 0):

If I where you, I would add a check to see if the token is expired on page load, if its expired, pass your information to the API, get an new token and use that one.